# PyQt formatting dropdowns

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a pyqt gui with several elements and I'm no sure how I should be formatting this. Basically I want three drop down menu buttons at the top of the page,and when an option is selected, it displays an sqlite3 database table with the qtableview widget. Any help on how I can format the drop downs? (Or any good resources for formatting pyqt in general?) Thanks!

Edit: Here is what I tried:

```py
self.com_btn = QComboBox('Com')
self.sec_btn = QComboBox('Sec')
self.sto_btn = QComboBox('Sto')

self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
self.hbox.addStretch(1)
self.hbox.addWidget(self.com_btn)
self.hbox.addWidget(self.sec_btn)
self.hbox.addWidget(self.sto_btn)
self.setLayout(self.hbox)
```

edit: image

[image]

Comment: Yeah sorry ignore that part (editing it out)

Comment: I thought it would just make a drop down with one label of 'Com'?

Comment: The QComboBoxes are populated from columns of an sqlite3 database (the strings are just place holders for now)

Comment: Yes it is. There are different tables, where a specific column is each combo box. I mostly need help arranging the combo boxes horizontally across the top of the app, so I can display a table below it.

Answer (score 2):

For an easy one-liner you can just style it like this:

```
self.com_btn.setStyleSheet('QComboBox {border: 1px solid gray;}')
```

Or you can make a stylesheet file, and add it to your app in the main function:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    css = open('path/to/my.css', 'r').read()
    app.setStyleSheet(css)
    mainWindow = Window()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

You can style the QComboBox in many ways:

```
QComboBox {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 1px 18px 1px 3px;
    min-width: 6em;
}

QComboBox:editable {
    background: white;
}

QComboBox:!editable, QComboBox::drop-down:editable {
    background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                stop: 0 #E1E1E1, stop: 0.4 #DDDDDD,
                                stop: 0.5 #D8D8D8, stop: 1.0 #D3D3D3);
}
```

For more, you can check the official documentation:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qcombobox